# How to convert date format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd base on RIDE python robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

If i got the message from the webpage to `18/05/2020`. I want to convert it to this format: `2020-05-18`
I tried using the date of `% Y-% m-% d` conversion, but there was an error that the value Mismatch error 
How should i do ?

Comment: Please stop adding additional & different questions as answers. This is not how Stackoverflow works; it is not a forum. It is also not "do this for me site" - the audience here will help you with specific problems, but you do have to show you put some effort beforehand.

Comment: If you are asking about code that generated an error, please show us both the code and the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `Convert Date` from `DateTime` library and to specify both result format and input forward:

```
${converted}    Convert Date    18/05/2020    result_format=%Y-%m-%d    date_format=%d/%m/%Y
```

Comment: Please help 
How to compare date on robot framework 

Example :
19/05/2020 <= 17/06/2020 (compare lessthan and equal )

Expected Result =  True